# Strange behaviour in NetBeans + JAVA + JavaScript for "{" and "}"

Tags: java, javascript, netbeans

I observed a strange behaviour in NetBeans + JAVA;
Inside my code I have the following lines:

```
function createForm(input1, input2, input3, whereToPlace){
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.method = "post";
form.action = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login?action=login';
form.id = "loginForm";
form.appendChild(input1);
form.appendChild(input2);
form.appendChild(input3);
document.getElementById(whereToPlace).appendChild(form);
return form.id;
```

And a simple button:

```
buton = document.createElement("button");
buton.innerHTML = "magicButon";
buton.onclick = function(){document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();};
```

When I push the button the browser (Google Chrome) displays the following link:

```
"$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/login?action=login"
```

Thus, incorrect - "{" and "}" are transformed in "%7B" and "%7D" - i.e., their ASCII codes.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: This doesn't look like Java, this looks like JavaScript...

Comment: It's JavaScript inside JSP in JAVA

Comment: Try double quotes. Your expression language call isn't being interpreted.

Comment: @ Elliot Frisch: already tried, no success